# Acivity , threading issues

Tags: android

I'm new to android and I have some unresolved problems:

- My project have two Activities:

  - Welcome (displays layout1).
  - MainDisplay (displays layout2).

  ```
  // Welcome.java
  public class Welcome extends Activity {
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

          run();

      }
  ```

  ```
  public void startMainAct() {
      Intent dIntent = new Intent(Welcome.this, MainDisplay.class);
      Welcome.this.startActivity(dIntent);
      finish();
  }

  public void run() {     
      try{                                            
          Thread.sleep(3000);         
      }                                               
      catch(Exception ex)                             
      {                                               
      }                                               
      finally{
          startMainAct();     
      }       
  }
  ```

  }

  // MainDisplay.java
  public class MainDisplay extends Activity implements Runnable {
      private static Thread m_thread = null;

  `@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.layout2);

      if (m_thread == null)           
      {           
          m_thread = new Thread(this);        
          m_thread .start();          
      }
  }

  public void run()                                   
  {                                                   
      try{                                            
          Thread.sleep(3000);         
      }                                               
      catch(Exception ex)                             
      {                                               
      }                                               
      finally{                                        
          finish();
      }       
  }`

  }

  1. When I run as New Configuration for Android (launch Welcome activity) using Eclipse,
     I see two apps with the same name (one runs Welcome activity, another runs MainDisplay activity) present in AVD.
     I don't understand here, why there are two but not only the one which will run the first activity (Welcome)?
  2. When it runs, I can't not see the layout of Welcome activity (just blank white screen), but after 3s it still starts the other activity?
  3. When I implements Runnable for the Welcome activity, it works OK? Could you please explain how it works?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run as New Configuration for Android (launch Welcome activity) using Eclipse, I see two apps with the same name (one runs Welcome activity, another runs MainDisplay activity) present in AVD. I don't understand here, why there are two but not only the one which will run the first activity (Welcome)?

You probably have the `<intent-filter>` `launcher` set for both. Only the first `Activity` to show should be the `launcher`.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

> When it runs, I can't not see the layout of Welcome activity (just blank white screen), but after 3s it still starts the other activity?

You call `run()` which calls `sleep()` on the main `Thread` which will keep your `UI` from being able to do anything for those 3 seconds then you start the other `Activity` as soon as that time is up. This is almost always, if not always, a bad idea.

> When I implements Runnable for the Welcome activity, it works OK? Could you please explain how it works?

You are running it on a separate `Thread` so that `Thread` sleeps instead of the `UI Thread`.

Comment: You're right. 
I'm clear now.
Thank you very much! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Thread.sleep() that will hold your UI.
Use Timer to delay 3 seconds and jump to MainActivity

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent dIntent = new Intent(Welcome.this, MainDisplay.class);
        Welcome.this.startActivity(dIntent);
        finish();
    }
}, 3000);
```